# Needed force to reach specific point for the ball

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, velocity

I am making a billiard game and need to push white ball to move other balls which should pocket so I need to calculate the force. I have mass, friction, distances, angles, collision point, origin point and destination point

How can I calculate the needed force to push the ball to reach the specific point in a 3D world?

Comment: There are a lot of different questions here: the dynamics of the queue striking the ball, the friction on the rolling ball, the ball collisions and the bounces off the cushions. There is no simple answer.

Comment: We don't use cue to hit, it is just for animation and we add force to the ball without anything to lost the energy. The friction of the ball is 0.05
 - The friction of the table is 2.8
 - The bounciness of the cushion is 0.02
 - The bounciness of the ball is 0.95
 - The linear drag of the ball is 0.4
 - The mass of the ball is 0.1701